# Why does javafx.scene.Group constructor accept Collection<Node> and not Collection<? extends Node>?

Tags: java, javafx-8

Suppose I have a list of circle nodes:

```
List<Circle> circles = Arrays.asList(new Circle(), new Circle());
```

If I want to create a `javafx.scene.Group`, I cannot use the constructor

```
Group group = new Group(circles); // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

but have to add my nodes like this:

```
Group group = new Group();
group.getChildren().addAll(circles);
```

Why does the Group constructor only accept `Collection<Node>` and not `Collection<? extends Node>`, given it only delegates to `getChildren().addAll(...)` anyways (which is covariant)?